# How do I make ```zenity --password``` input into a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zenity

## How do I make `zenity --password` input into a variable?

I'm using `zenity --password` to get input from the user and I'm trying to save it as a variable.

### Here are some commands I've tried:

1. `var=${zenity --password};`
2. `zenity var=--password`
3. `var=zenity --password`

None of these work.

### Error Codes:

I got error codes from commands #2 and #3.
The command #2 error code was:

`You must specify a dialog type. See 'zenity --help' for details`

The command #3 error code was:

`-bash: --password: command not found`.

I'm not that familiar with bash, and I only know a few basic commands. The `--password` command is from Zenity (`sudo apt-get install zenity`). If somebody answers, thank you for helping!

### Links

**Zenity Manual** - https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/

**Password Command** - https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/password.html.en

Comment: `var=$(zenity --password)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input
> instead of the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a newline
> character.

```
zenity --password | sudo -S some_app_here
```

Example

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSWORD=$(zenity --password)
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S "command"

echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S "command"

exit
```